# The Atomic Testing Museum: Suitable for small children?

Tags: usa, children, museums, las-vegas, geek-travel

A friend of mine is going to California this summer. Since he is generally very interested in science and technology he is considering visiting [The Atomic Testing Museum](http://www.nationalatomictestingmuseum.org/) in Las Vegas. He has two small children (5 and 7 years) and is a little bit unsure if this museum is suitable for them.

For sure they won't understand a lot, but could they get scared by the exhibition there? Invisible radiation that can cause death, huge explosions and weapons of mass destruction may not be suited for small children, but it also heavily depends on how the exhibition is presented.

So can anyone recommend if the exhibition is suitable for small children?

Comment: I wrote a story about a family of cockroaches that survives a nuclear holocaust when I was 10.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Been there!

It is a really nice exhibition, but I would have expected a bit more to see. It's not scary at all, more exiting and entertaining in a '1950's amazement' kind of way. You wont see any "death and destruction" there, the worst thing is probably the [Declassified U.S. Nuclear Test Film #55](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=wA8z94MXo9M#t=578s). 
I think the science part falls a bit too short, but it is well explained.

Sadly, no pictures were allowed in the museum otherwise I would have attached one.